# qtree and booklet packages

Tags: qtree, booklet

I am using the booklet package, and I would like to draw syntactic trees with the qtree package. However it seems the two packages are in conflict: just by stating the qtree package cut the whole page in half. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[print]{booklet}
\setpdftargetpages
\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\firstrefdash}{}
\def\exr{\setcounter{ExNo}{0}\ex}
\usepackage{tipa} 
\usepackage{qtree}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

  bla bla bla 

ex.[(3)] \Tree [.DP [.D the ]]

\end{document}
```

Any idea of how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your conflicting code?

Comment: That's what `booklet` does! By default it makes four-page signatures, so two pages are always produced, that should then be printed on both sides of a sheet. I see no difference when `qtree` is loaded an when it's not (in this case I just added some mock text instead of the tree).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I might not make myself clear. This is what I get when using `qtree` and `booklet` together: [click](https://postimg.org/image/e8t5i8th3/)

Comment: @RobertP. please don't use external image hosting sites. I you want tow show an image, you can always edit your question and include one.

Comment: Dis you try to move the qtree package before booklet?

Comment: I gave up on `booklet` a while ago. It worked well at one time, but hasn't worked properly for me for several years. (And I gather from questions that others have no better luck.)

Comment: That said, your example works fine, even when I add 3 and a half pages of Kant with `kantlipsum`.

Comment: Hi there! I tried this morning to move the `qtree` package before `booklet`. Samcarter, you were right! Thank you!!